# LaunchedEffect not called on Box while UI testing in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, ui-testing

I am running a simple Test on LaunchedEffect:

```
@Test
fun testSomeState() {
    composeTestRule.setContent {
        SomeComposable {
            println("click $it")
        }
    }
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("Zivi")
        .performClick()
        .assertExists()
}

@Composable
fun SomeComposable(onClick: (Int) -> Unit) {
    var someState by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Button(modifier = Modifier.testTag("Zivi").pointerInteropFilter {
        someState = when (it.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> { 1 }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> { 2 }
            else -> { someState  }
        }
        true

    }, onClick = { }) {}

    LaunchedEffect(someState) {
        println("LaunchedEffect someState $someState") // prints "LaunchedEffect someState 0" 
                                                       // and then "LaunchedEffect someState 2"
        if (someState == 2) { onClick(someState) }
    }
}
```

---

### This works well, however, if i change Button to a Box, like this:

```
@Composable
fun SomeComposable(onClick: (Int) -> Unit) {
    var someState by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.testTag("Zivi").pointerInteropFilter {
        someState = when (it.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> { 1 }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> { 2 }
            else -> { someState  }
        }
        true

    }) {}

    LaunchedEffect(someState) {
        println("LaunchedEffect someState $someState") // prints "LaunchedEffect someState 0"
        if (someState == 2) { onClick(someState) }
    }
}
```

Then the LaunchedEffect is not called on performClick, can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: It may be related to the fact that your `Box` has zero size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box composable by default doesn't have any size so technically, when the user clicks on any portion of the screen, the event doesn't get consumed by the `Box`.

You can verify this by adding a `background(color = Color.Green)` modifier to your box and observe that no section of the screen gets colored green as expected.

You can fix this by  setting a `size` modifier for your `Box`.

You can change your box implementation to this and it should work. I am using `fillMaxSize` here

```
@Composable
fun SomeComposable(onClick: (Int) -> Unit) {
    var someState by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .testTag("Zivi")
        .pointerInteropFilter {
            someState = when (it.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    1
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    2
                }
                else -> {
                    someState
                }
            }
            true

        }) {}

    LaunchedEffect(someState) {
        println("LaunchedEffect someState $someState") // prints "LaunchedEffect someState 0"
        // and then "LaunchedEffect someState 2"
        if (someState == 2) {
            onClick(someState)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the problem with my example was that Box had no size, when adding some size like fillMaxSize() to it, the LaunchedEffect is called.
Unfortunately in my original problem (which i simplified to this experiment for understanding) i still dont get the LaunchedEffect call. will update further.